# Loss of variables in ThingsBoard using HTTP

Tags: http, variables, send, loss, thingsboard

I am studying the time it takes to send different variables to the same device using the HTTP protocol. The first test that I carried out is to send a single variable to a device more than 50 times, however, when analyzing the results in ThingsBoard and verifying that the variable was sent 50 times, I realized that the ThingsBoard platform did not receive the 50 shipments and the last 7 were lost. Carrying out different tests to study this phenomenon, I have concluded that from 40 shipments most of the shipments are lost. Is it known why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the troubleshooting guide of the Documentation:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting/

You should see, if there are any timeouts or processing errors.

I also witnessed the same behaviour sometimes if using In-Memory Queue. After switching to Kafka as queue, I could resolve this problem:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardQueue=kafka#step-4-choose-thingsboard-queue-service

Comment: Addition: You may also consider switching from HTTP to MQTT to increase the performance